# What does it mean to have "whipped top"? (Shakespeare/archaic usage)

Tags: archaicisms, shakespeare

e.g. in the Merry Wives of Windsor, Act V, Scene 1:

> Since I plucked geese, played truant, and whipped top, I knew not what it was to be beaten till lately.

I assume it's some form of game or diversion, but I can't seem to find out what. It's also used in Hudibras:

> For as whipp'd tops, and bandy'd balls,
>
> The learned hold, are animals

Any context or explanation for these quotations would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is archaic? Okay, now I feel old. Granted I would have thought it an old-fashioned game as a child and knew it went back to at least Victorian times (learning later it went back further again), but I did still whip a top as a child. (Or tried to, it always just made it fall over for me).

Comment: @Jon Hannah - 3 years later. Have a look at my answer below. You can still buy these in 2018.  Just Google 'whip and top toy' and then clcik on *Shopping*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to indicate that the toy top was spun by whipping it with a stick - much the same way that "rolling hoops" was played.

Comment: Either that, or a string was wrapped around the top and attached to a stick (as a whip is). Cracking the "whip" would release the top at quite a speed.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVdKa7Rl3P4)'s a video.

Comment: @StoneyB - That's really cool - never saw it before.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, presumably it means to play with a spinning top? Wouldn't have known these were popular in Shakespeare's time!

Answer (score 0):

It's not even archaic. You can still buy these in some toy-shops, especially those frequented by a particular type of middle-class educated people.

[image]

[image]

Extract from Children's Games (1560)

[image]

Chinese Men Whipping Tops on Ice Surface  -  https://www.toysperiod.com/blog/games/discovering-spinning-tops/